# AudioListener камеры отключен, но звуки все-равно слышно на android

Tags: android, unity3d

В игре чтобы отключить звук я просто отключал на камере компонент AudioListener. И звук действительно отключался при запуске в юнити-редакторе. Но при установке apk файла звук сохраняется (картинка кнопки меняется, а значит тап срабатывает). Есть ли отличие в обработке звука на андроиде? Далее код кнопки отключения звука:

```
public void MusicOnOff()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("music") == "off")
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("music", "on");
        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = MusicOn;
        Camera.main.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = true;
    } else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("music", "off");
        GetComponent<Image>().sprite = MusicOff;
        Camera.main.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
    }
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://www.cyberforum.ru/unity/thread2366086.html. Если кратко, то вам нужно изменять параметры volume и pause как статические. То есть не с помощью GetComponent(),  а AudioListener.volume, AudioListener.pause

Comment: @МаксимФисман спасибо, проверю как доберусь до редактора, думаю сработает. Странно, что на компьютере корректно работает и тот код, что привел я, но не работает под андроидом.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Да, сработало. Хотя все-равно остается вопрос как отключать звук на конкретных камерах =) Но для текущей маленькой задачи это вполне подходящий выход.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ввиду того, что моя подсказка в комментариях помогла Виталию, дам полноценный ответ.

Компонент [AudioListener](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2018.4/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) имеет параметры float [volume](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-volume.html) (громкость) и bool [pause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) (пауза).

Перейдя по ссылкам можно увидеть, что они *статические*, что говорит о том, что их нельзя изменять через `GetComponent<AudioListener>().volume` или `GetComponent<AudioListener>().pause`. Их можно настраивать только так:

```
AudioListener.volume = ...;
AudioListener.pause = ...;
```

На сцене *может* быть несколько камер, но документация говорит: `В каждой сцене может быть только один Audio Listener для корректной работы системы.`